# Wordpress Shortcode with Select from table syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, syntax, shortcode

I have a table called `wp_pp_seller`, and there I have different columns, two of which are `user_id` and `credits`. I'm trying to create a shortcode in `function.php` in a child theme.

My code is as follows:

```
function custom_shortcode()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $credits = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT {$credits} * FROM {$wp_pp_seller} WHERE user_id=current_user_id");
    mysql_query($credits);
    echo "<p>, {$credits} creditos</p>";
}

add_filter('init', 'add_custom_shortcode');

function add_custom_shortcode()
{
    add_shortcode('pp_credits', 'custom_shortcode');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I encourage direct queries of the database, but I'm sure that you have not sent the database the current user id like you think you have:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$credits = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT {$credits} * FROM {$wp_pp_seller} WHERE user_id=$current_user->ID")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$credits = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT {$credits} * FROM {$wp_pp_seller} WHERE user_id=" . $current_user->ID)
```

Comment: Nice answer.  I think you got it right. *Off-Topic* my favorite JavaScript teacher is named Thomas Wilburn

Comment: We had the same answer. HA HA Funny!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  function custom_shortcode() {

        global $wpdb;
       $user_id = get_current_user_id();
                $credits = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT {$credits} * FROM {$wp_pp_seller} WHERE user_id=".$user_id);        

                echo "<p>, ".$credits." creditos</p>";

    }

    add_filter('init', 'add_custom_shortcode');

    function add_custom_shortcode() {
       add_shortcode('pp_credits', 'custom_shortcode');
    }
```

You can use `$wpdb->last_error`  for printing the mysql error. so that you can track mysql error